# Youtube videos in webView using Youtube API

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html, android-youtube-api

My current problem: I am using a webView to show web content in my app. In one link (which I need to show in webView) there is nothing more but just 3 youtube videos from 1 channel.

Question: How to use youtube API that it would automatically detect these videos and play correctly when the mentioned link is being opened?

I tried to use only webView to show youtube content but I am facing many problems with it - youtube video sometimes doesn't play at all, there is problems with Android version compatibility, etc. And as I read in general in forums - webView itself is not recommended to be used as html5 youtube video player. Most people suggests to use "new Youtube API". So how exactly implement this youtube API in my case?

Any examples? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Google release Youtube Android player api so that you can import this library to use
it's a good video player for watch YouTube video and playlist
 [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Comment: So I am talking exactly about this library. But maybe somebody could give exact code example how to implement it considering my case?